How to have horizontal scrollbar on a table and a vertical scrollbar on the body page while also using position sticky for thead of an html table?
It's really difficult to explain what I need in the title, so here's an example.
This is my table:


body { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}

header { 
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.header__info-wrapper { 
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 10px;
}

.infoboard__wrapper { 
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.title { 
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.view {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100vw;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;  

  table-layout: fixed;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top:0;  
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;    
}

table th:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)) {
  width: 300px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  /* overflow-x: auto; */
  height: 100vh;
}

.sticky-col {  
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
}

th.sticky-col{
  z-index: 2;
}

.first-col {
  width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  left: 0;  
}

.second-col {
  width: 150px;
  min-width: 150px;
  max-width: 150px;
  left: 100px;
}

.wrapped-content{
  width: 250px;
  white-space: normal;
}
<header>
    <div class="header__info-wrapper">
      <div class="title">Some Title</div>
      <div class="infoboard__wrapper">
        <div class="basic__info">
          <div>Total Number:</div>
          <div>
            <ifx-number-indicator id="number__indicator-total"></ifx-number-indicator>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="basic__info">
          <div>Completed:</div>
          <div>
            <ifx-number-indicator id="number__indicator-completed"></ifx-number-indicator>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="basic__info">
          <div>Planned:</div>
          <div>
            <ifx-number-indicator id="number__indicator-planned"></ifx-number-indicator>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="view">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="sticky-col first-col">Preview</th>
            <th class="sticky-col second-col">Component</th>
            <th>Version 1</th>
            <th>Version 2</th>
            <th>Version 3</th>
            <th>Version 4</th>
            <th>Version 5</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">1</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Mark</td>
            <td>Ham</td>
            <td>Micro</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">2</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Jacob</td>
            <td>Smith</td>
            <td>Adob Adob Adob AdobAdob Adob Adob Adob Adob</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">3</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td><div class="wrapped-content">Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</div></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">3</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">4</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">5</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">6</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
            <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
            <td>Wen</td>
            <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>



This is the behavior that I want! Fixed th and fixed first two cols + fixed horizontal scrollbar.
The problem is that, because the horizontal scrollbar appears on the body, the whole body is moving! So, the content inside Header moves too. I don't want that. I want the horizontal scrollbar to only move the content inside the table, not the whole body. I want the vertical scollbar to be on the body so the entire page can scroll down.
If you uncomment the overflow-x: auto;, then the horizontal scrollbar moves the table content, but the vertical scrollbar only moves the table content too, and not the entire body, which is what I want! On top of that, because of the header content, there are actually two scrollbars.
How to achieve what I want? How to make the horizontal scrollbar only move the content of the table while the vertical one move the entire page?
Update:
Screenshots of td border  before scroll movement.

Screenshots of td border after scroll movement.

Screenshots of th border before scroll movement.

Screenshots of th border after scroll movement.

Borders do not align:


Making the horizontal scrollbar fixed is not possible yet but to make the table X-axis scroll instead of the whole body scrolling Horizontally and set the table height dynamically according to the header. This will result in almost the same impression as your requirements.
The steps needed to be done are:

Add overflow-x: hidden; to the body element
Add width: 100% and overflow: scroll to the wrapper element of the table.
Calculate the header height using JavaScript and set the height as a CSS custom property
Finally add height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height) - 15px); to the wrapper element. (15px is the scrollbar height)

EDIT: The second problem you are getting is the border getting invisible when you are scrolling horizontally or vertically. I have tried multiple solutions and found the answer. The cause of this problem is the border-collapse: collapse on the table element. Revoming it and changing the border-spacing to 0 does the job and the border now stays while scrolling but there was a problem with this. The td and th border overlaps the sibling border and create a thick  (2px) border border at some areas. I have solved this issue by removing the border from td and th and replacing it with the box-shadow extending 1px with 0 blur. Another 1 small change is the table top-border was missing so I have added the border-top: 1px; to the th elements in the thead. Now it looks perfect.
Additionally, I have changed the left position of .second-col element "Component" to 150px. Now this prevents it from moving horizontally as per your comment request.
You can preview the updated result in the snippet below


const headerEl = document.querySelector("header");
const headerHeight = headerEl.offsetHeight;
const wrapperEl = document.querySelector(".wrapper");

wrapperEl.style.setProperty('--header-height', `${headerHeight}px`);
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

header {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.header__info-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
}

.infoboard__wrapper {
    display: flex;
    gap: 15px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.title {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.view {
    margin: auto;
    width: 100vw;
}

table {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;

    /* Removed the border-collapse and added border spacing 0  */
    border-spacing: 0;
}

thead tr th {
    /* Added the border top to the table header */
    border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

th {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

td,
th {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    
    /* Removed the border */
    border: none;

    /* Added the box-shadow as the border */
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #dddddd;
    
    background-color: white;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

table th:not(:nth-child(1)):not(:nth-child(2)) {
    width: 300px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) td {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh - var(--header-height) - 15px);
    overflow: scroll;
}

.sticky-col {
    position: sticky;
    z-index: 1;
}

th.sticky-col {
    z-index: 2;
}

.first-col {
    width: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    left: 0;
}

.second-col {
    width: 150px;
    min-width: 150px;
    max-width: 150px;
    left: 150px;
}

.wrapped-content {
    width: 250px;
    white-space: normal;
}
<header>
    <div class="header__info-wrapper">
        <div class="title">Some Title</div>
        <div class="infoboard__wrapper">
            <div class="basic__info">
                <div>Total Number:</div>
                <div>
                    <ifx-number-indicator id="number__indicator-total"></ifx-number-indicator>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="basic__info">
                <div>Completed:</div>
                <div>
                    <ifx-number-indicator id="number__indicator-completed"></ifx-number-indicator>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="basic__info">
                <div>Planned:</div>
                <div>
                    <ifx-number-indicator id="number__indicator-planned"></ifx-number-indicator>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<div class="view">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="sticky-col first-col">Preview</th>
                    <th class="sticky-col second-col">Component</th>
                    <th>Version 1</th>
                    <th>Version 2</th>
                    <th>Version 3</th>
                    <th>Version 4</th>
                    <th>Version 5</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">1</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Mark</td>
                    <td>Ham</td>
                    <td>Micro</td>
                    <td>Micro</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">2</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Jacob</td>
                    <td>Smith</td>
                    <td>Adob Adob Adob AdobAdob Adob Adob Adob Adob</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">3</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="wrapped-content">Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">3</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">4</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">5</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">6</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="sticky-col first-col">7</td>
                    <td class="sticky-col second-col">Larry</td>
                    <td>Wen</td>
                    <td>Goog Goog Goog GoogGoog Goog Goog Goog Goog Goog</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>



Note: You might be seeing a little overlap on the last right cells and the td element right border not aligning properly with the th element. This is because cells are missing in this table. If you even add empty cells (td elements) all over the missing spots. It will be fixed and will look perfect. Its summary is: "Make sure that the count td in every tr element matches the count of th elements that are in the thead element."

This doesn't work. The vertical scrollbar stays on the body, but it doesn't scroll the table.  The table scroll is just hidden. Also the horizontal scroll that scrolls the table is not fixed.

I have updated my answer, Can you check it out again?

Thanks! Is there a way to prevent the movement of the second col "components" when you use the horizontal scrollbar? Also, same question for the th rows when you use the vertical scrollbar. There is some small movement, and there is also a tiny gap between the th and the table.

Sorry, but I haven't understood 100% of what you are trying to say. Still, there are some things that I can tell you. If you want to remove the small gap above the first 'th' elements row you can add transform: translateY(-1px); to all the th in the thead. This will remove the small gap above the th row. Secondly, to stop the "component" column from moving, you can change the left CSS value of the 'second col' to (149 or 150) to prevent it from moving horizontally. Hope this helps!

So, there are 3 problems now. One is that when I move the horizontal scrollbar, the td borders scroll too and there is gap that opens up in the first two cols because their borders move with the scrollbar! Is there a way to prevent this? I updated the question to show you screenshot of what I mean. Second problem is that same thing happens with the th bottom border. When I scroll down the vertical scroll, the top and bottom border of the th cols gets hidden because wit moves with the scroll. Also included in the screenshot. Third problem is that there is a tiny movement of the th when scroll.

Phew!  I have updated my answer as per your new requirements. Check the snippet, if this meets your conditions and works fine. ‍

It seems to work on the snippet. Are your new changes the ones with a comment? I am asking so I don't copy/paste everything again. I just want to add the new changes.

My English is not too good but as I understand. Yes, I have updated the code as the answer to the 3 problems you asked in the comments. Is not not right?

Yes, The ones with a comment are my new changes

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
